# How to insert <gi> cursor at the end of line in the Firefox extension Vimperator

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, vimperator

How would I use Vimperator's insert shortcut `<gi>` to immediate end of line?

By default it is inserted at the beginning on line which is annoying, because I don't ever find myself needing to go there.

example:

If I type the following into Google search:

> John ran as fast as he could but couldn't escape the wraith of the viscous dogs chasing him.

How would I then insert my cursor right after the period by default *only if there is text*?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a mapping into your vimperatorrc like that:

`noremap <leader>i gi<End>`

I used the leader key for this (explanation in `:h mapleader`), but you could use any other shortcut...